# unable to switch TTY in arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, tty

So I'm moving away from Ubuntu into the realm of Arch Linux.

In Ubuntu I was able to switch TTYs with `ctrl+alt+F1/F2...` and etc.

In Arch when I attempt this, I'm merely dumped to a black screen with a flashing underscore (the resolution looks to be non-native as well).

I followed the beginners guide at [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide) but to no avail.

I'm using a Thinkpad X220, with the `xf86-video-intel` driver (for my 2nd generation i7) and running i3 as my window manager.

Comment: Can you edit and add your `/etc/inittab`?

Comment: @Paul No inittab in Arch Linux anymore.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>This is based on [the OP's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/429511/unable-to-switch-tty-in-arch-linux#comment498880_429579) that should be an answer.</sub>

To switch TTYs I was using <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> which on my Thinkpad corresponds to TTY13-24 (which aren't configured). Simply by using <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> everything works as expected.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, but with my setup (ext kbd) I need to use the right ctrl key instead of left. But I have to use left alt because on the right is altgr which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `rc.multi` never ends, because one of daemons in the DAEMONS array is failing. Fire up a text editor on  `/etc/inittab` and edit this line from:

```
rm:2345:wait:/etc/rc.multi
```

to:

```
rm:2345:once:/etc/rc.multi
```

If it works now, it confirms my guess, so you need to find which daemon is failing and fix it.

Comment: actrually, ive figured it out -- as dumb as it sounds, i was using R_alt to switch TTYs, which on my thinkpad, correspond to TTY13-24 (which arent configured) simply by using L_alt, everything works as expected.

Comment: Arch doesn't use `inittab` anymore, since they switched to systemd.

Comment: @adam then best practise is to write the answer yourself and then mark it selected.